# Method interception in Jersey using Guice AOP

Tags: java, jersey, aop, guice

Is it possible to use Guice AOP to intercept an annotated method on a Jersey resource?

I have a successfully configured Guice integration working with Jersey with respect to Dependency Injection without any problems, however my configured Interceptor is not intercepting my annotated method at all.

**web.xml**

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.package.GuiceConfig</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**GuiceConfig configuration module**

```
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {

                bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), 
                                Matchers.annotatedWith(RequiredAuthority.class), 
                                new AuthorisationInterceptor());

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                params.put(JSP_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH, "/WEB-INF/jsp"); 
                params.put(FEATURE_FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, "true");
                params.put(PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "my.service.package");

                filter("/*").through(GuiceContainer.class, params);
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

**RequiredAuthority annotation**

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiredAuthority {
    String value();
}
```

**AuthorisationInterceptor aspect**

```
public class AuthorisationInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {

        // Allow invocation to process or throw an appropriate exception
    }
}
```

**TempResource JAX-RS resource class**

```
@Path("/temp")
public class TempResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RequiredAuthority("PERMISSION")
    public String getTemp() {

        // Return resource normally
    }
}
```

Comment: Late to the party, but it looks like [`@BindingAnnotation`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/BindingAnnotation.html) is also missing from `RequiredAuthority`.

Comment: Thank you, yes this also caused a problem at the time. Well worth noting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like configureServlets() isn't calling:

```
bind(TempResource.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the bind(TempResource.class) that I was missing, I was under the impression that the PROPERTY_PACKAGES parameter would scan the package for resources. I didn't need the @Singleton in the end.

Comment: Same problem may occure with @Transactional of Google-Persist handling